# template function pointer: "overloaded function with no contextual type information"

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I need an universal function pointer. I made this simple code below, but *g++* gives me an error if I try to assign a value to the function pointer.

```
TestMain.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
TestMain.cpp:11:21: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
```

The code:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    void func(char ch){}
};

template <class Class, class ret, class Arg1>
int Foo(ret (Class::* obj)(Arg1)){
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    Foo = &MyClass::func;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Foo` is a function. What exactly do you expect by doing `Foo = &MyClass::func;`?

Comment: Really... Well, anyway, I'll try to fix it to universal pointer, and will write here what I got...

Comment: I think you may be confused about function pointers in general.  You can't create a "universal" function pointer because a pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member-function are fundamentally different.  See here: http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of a pointer to member function would be in your case

```
void (MyClass::*mf1)(char) = &MyClass::func; // (1)
```

So the syntax to a pointer to member function is fundamentaly different. Also you can't declare a templated function pointer, so you can translate the above into templates, **the following is illegal**

```
template <class Class, class ret, class Arg1> // (2)
ret (Class::*pMf)(Arg1);
```

it fails with the following error

> 1>StackOverflow.cpp(23): error C2998: 'ret (__cdecl Class::* __cdecl pMf)(Arg1)' : cannot be a template definition

### What you can do

[**Solution 1**](http://ideone.com/yGznbw) : [alias templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

```
template<typename Class, typename ret, typename Arg1>
using pMemFun = ret (Class::*)(Arg1);

int main()
{
    pMemFun<MyClass, void, char> pF = &MyClass::func;
    return 0;
}
```

**Solution 2** : helper struct

Thnx 2 dyp for the tip on compiling in gcc.

Take a look at the following structure

```
template <class Class, class ret, class Arg1>
struct mFunPtr
{
    typedef ret (Class::*ptr)(Arg1);
};
```

This is a workaround to templatize the type of a pointer to member function. Using the above would allow code like

```
mFunPtr<MyClass, void, char>::ptr fPtr = &MyClass::func; // (3)
```

Now, is (3) + a struct definition better than (1) ? That's up to your taste;

Comment: Hmm why not use `auto` then? Of course, if you *need* to specify a type it doesn't help, but why not use `ret (Class::*)(Args...)` in those cases directly (instead of `pMemFun<Class, ret, Args...>`). Btw, that declaration `(2)` will be a legal *namespace scope* declaration in C++1y.

Comment: *"or until someone finds how to compile it in gcc"* Remove the `typename` to make it well-formed C++. It'll compile with g++ and clang++ then, not sure about MSVC though.

Comment: @dyp Thnx, I ammended the answer accordingly. I'm just mentioning (2) on the grounds that I can't rely on a standard that hasn't been released yet. As for auto, you said it, it would only solve direct initialization problems.

Comment: Yes, but when you don't directly initialize, i.e. when you need to explicitly supply some type, why use a type alias? (The only reason that comes to my mind is the weird `auto pF = pMemFun<MyClass, void, char>{&MyClass::func};`.) You can use `void (MyClass::*)(char)` directly when you need an explicit type.

Comment: An example : That pointer to member function could be an argument `A` to a template function `F` and depend on its parameters. Now (1) for ease of use (you may find the syntax less error prone) or (2) if `F` is a variadic template you may need to forward the parameter pack to `A` this way (If you click the link I provide the variadic template flavour)